# get upload image url for css in TYPO3

Tags: typo3

I am working on create an extension. My content got a upload part to upload image in the backend. I want to get that uploaded image to use as background image in css. Are there any ways to get the upload image url and which between inline css and css file which one i should use in this situation?

My element i want to set the background image:

Comment: Due to the possible change of the upload image, I would suggest using inline css for the background image. Otherwise you would need to write a dynamic css file.

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer to use inline styles for the background image. You can get the URL of the image with the f:uri.image view helper:

```
<div style="background-image:url({f:uri.image(src: '{imageField}')});">
```